# asp.net MVC 3 no default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Has anyone tried to deploy an asp.net mvc 3 website that uses the razor templates?  The project does not create a default page and not sure if this changes in some way?

Comment: I'll go ahead and ask, but is there a homecontroller with a default view?

Comment: yeah all that but as it creates no default file i am not sure if i copy over my usual aspx page with the same codebehind, they just dont produce it anymore

Comment: Can you confirm that you have tried this same operation using the 'Old' view Engine and it worked as expected?   Also, is everything working as expected other than this default page issue?

Comment: Or, is it a problem with not setting the Build Action to Content on the pages? When you add a view using the Add View dialog it doesn't mark them properly. When you deploy they're not copied to the server. Ah, you're asking about the Default.aspx page that was created in older versions of MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have several projects in the pipeline that work on both IIS 7 and 6 (test servers) without any issues with a missing default.aspx page. I don't have any production code in effect but so far it's not an issue.

I would say the issue with a missing default.aspx page would rely on the server not using the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in the web.config. Otherwise a default.aspx page isn't necessary for handling. As long as IIS uses the mvc module to handle requests.

Comment: whay hay wicked thats the ticket, thought it was a bug that it never created the default file anymore, but that tag is nice and works a treat also solved all other problems too